# Access an API via Node.js

Tags: node.js, api

Using the sample Python code provided by the Bureau of Labor Statistics I was able to successfully access their API and print the JSON containing the data series in the console.  Python code below:

```
#BLS query.
headers = {'Content-type': 'application/json'}
data = json.dumps({"seriesid": ['CES0000000001'],"startyear":"2010", "endyear":"2019"})
result = requests.post('https://api.bls.gov/publicAPI/v2/timeseries/data/', data=data, headers=headers)
print(result.text)
```

While the Python code works just fine, I would prefer to use JS, but have been unsuccessful in doing so.  I have tried using fetch, but I am not making any progress.  See JS code below:

```
fetch('https://api.bls.gov/publicAPI/v2/timeseries/data/', {
        method: 'POST',
        headers: {
            'Content-type': 'application/json'
        },
        body: JSON.stringify({seriesid: ['CES0000000001'], startyear:"2010", endyear:"2019"})
    }) 
    .then(function(response) {response.json()}) 
    .then(function(json) {console.log(json)});
```

I am sure I am messing up something simple here, but I'm at a loss.  Any help would be greatly appreciated.  For reference, additional info from the BLS on their API can be found at this link:

https://www.bls.gov/developers/api_signature_v2.htm

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use regular JavaScript's fetch in Node.js, it won’t work, One reason for that is because, NodeJs doesn't make requests via the browser, but Fetch API was made to make requests via the browser

You’d have to use a package called `node-fetch`, it's just like the regular fetch, but for NodeJs.

You can get it here -> https://www.npmjs.com/package/node-fetch

or you can also use the standard NodeJS `HTTP` package.

or packages like `axios` or `request` to make HTTP requests in NodeJS

Answer (score 0):

Try using this,

const data = { username: 'example' };

```
fetch('https://api.bls.gov/publicAPI/v2/timeseries/data', {
  method: 'POST', // or 'PUT'
  headers: {
    'Content-Type': 'application/json',
  },
  body: JSON.stringify(data),
})
.then((response) => response.json())
.then((data) => {
  console.log('Success:', data);
})
.catch((error) => {
  console.error('Error:', error);
});
```

But what I think the real problem might be that you are using an API which has authentication used, so make sure that you are using the api key along with the post req itself.

if you can have the api documentation, please refer it and see how to make a authenticated request to the server.